# Forcing the user to see where my hidden nav is

Tags: css

I'm coding a website at the moment, and it has some kind of vertical nav to the left. A css transition is triggered once the user hovers on a div next to the nav's right. The problem is i'm not sure every single user will notice the navigation menu is there.

So I want it to be there the moment the page loads, and then go back to its original place, so that fist, the user notices it. Then it transitions to hide behind the left hand side of the screen. When the user will want to switch to a different page, he/she will have already seen the nav slowly move and will get it, hover the arrow to make the menu appear.

How can i perform this task, either in jQuery or CSS ? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Those kinds of tools exist out there.

Comment: I don't know what to try, that's why i'm here. Can you please just help me out.

Comment: This isn't a spoon fed community.  You have to attempt to try, then ask for help where you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if users are getting confused about where your navigation menu is, then it's a big hint that you should revise your user experience. Make it obvious for those old biddies to work your website.

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("nav").animate({
            left: -200
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UnPDj/

EDIT: added hover state: http://jsfiddle.net/UnPDj/1/

Comment: I'm sure that's what OP is looking for... Wish you would have given them some time to produce something that showed that they were making an effort though.

Comment: Dude, this is a matter of time. That's a website i have to do in 3 days, and i really can't afford thinking or trying things. I just needed a timed hover trigger. Thank you man.

Comment: I'll let you figure out a pure CSS approach yourself. A hint is in the second edit to my post. This will make it more compatible for browsers without Javascript enabled.

Comment: Could that be delaying the transition using CSS ?

Comment: Yes, or using CSS keyframe animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try a

```
<body onLoad="function();">
```

to initiate a little javascript to change the menu's styles to allow it to be visible, with a timing function to move it back to hidden state after a couple of seconds. 
Or you could create a little tab placeholder to reveal the menu. There are too many ways to do if, so if you could be more specific on "how" you intend to hide and reveal the menu, it would be easier to give you specifics.